# Where is the strech tool?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

In a tutorial to make an anvil, Andrew uses a UV - strech tool. It appears in the UV-Editor by pressing N. Where can I find this in the current version (2.93.5) ?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.80 it is found in the overlays menu:

[image]